# Cross script variable isnt being found

Tags: unity-game-engine, global-variables

I know this is one of the simplest things you can do in C# but whatever I do theres always an error. Im making a UI where you can click and change the grid size (of my building mechanic). Its default is at `2.5` and I want to access the variable `yourGridSize` which is located on the script `GroundPlacementController`. The script thats trying to access it is called `GridChangerScript`. The only error I get is in `GridChangerScript` and its whenever I call the variable it says it doesn't recognize it.

Heres `GroundPlacementController` (shortened)

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class GroundPlacementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]   
    public float yourGridSize = 2.5f;
```

And heres `GridChangerScript`

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject gridChanger = GameObject.Find("GridChanger");
        GroundPlacementController groundPlacementController = gridChanger.GetComponent<GroundPlacementController>();
        float yourGridSize = 10f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you call ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad I tried changing yourGridSize in the update function but it gave me the same error

Comment: Edit and post that portion of code please

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a new local variable

```c#
float yourGridSize = 10f;
```

you have to access the value of that instance reference like

```c#
groundPlacementController.yourGridSize = 10.0f;
```

---

Just to be sure

```c#
GameObject gridChanger = GameObject.Find("GridChanger");
```

is called in a script called `GridChanger` ... is it possible that both components are attached to the same GameObject anyway?

Of this is the case you could just do

```c#
var groundPlacementController = GetComponent<GroundPlacementController>();
```

---

We just found out that the issue is also that you have that component multiple times on the same `GameObject`.

In general Unity is not really made for having the same component multiple times on the same object. As you noticed e.g. in the comments `GetComponent` will allways only get the first component of that type. Also if you want to reference them in UnityEvents (e.g. `onClick` of the `Button` component) you can allways only access the first encounter of the component. The proper setup would be to have one child GameObject for each instance of that type.

However there are workarounds for this.

You can e.g. use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) to get all components of that type on that GameObject or any of it's children (recursively)

```c#
GameObject gridChanger = GameObject.Find("GridChanger");

// Optionally you can pass in a true to also find inactive or disabled components
GroundPlacementController[] groundPlacementControllers = gridChanger.GetComponentsInChildren<GroundPlacementController>();
```

Or if those are the only occurrences of that type in the entire Scene you can use [`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) (only active and endabled components)

```c#
GroundPlacementController[] groundPlacementControllers = FindObjectsOfType<GroundPlacementController>();
```

And than for setting all their `yourGridSize` iterate through them

```c#
foreach(var groundPlacementController in groundPlacementControllers)
{
    groundPlacementController.yourGridSize = 10.0f;
}
```

---

**Update**

As you want to also read out a certain text first do

```c#
GroundPlacementController[] groundPlacementControllers = FindObjectsOfType<GroundPlacementController>();

foreach(var groundPlacementController in groundPlacementControllers)
{
    // get the childs text
    var childText = groundPlacementController.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);

    // Convert the text to float
    float textValue = float.TryParse(childText.text, out textValue ? textValue : 0.0f;
    groundPlacementController.yourGridSize = textValue;
}
```

*Notes:*

- *For a `public` you do not need to add `[SerializeField]` since `public` fields are serialized automatically.*
- *you should remove empty MonoBehaviour events like your `Update`. Even if they are empty they are called by Unity causing unnecessary overhead.*

Comment: that works but it seems like the variable is only being called in GridChangerScript when it needs to be changed in GroundPlacementController. What I mean is yourGridSize is changing in the script GridChangerScript, and not in groundPlacementController so it dosent actually affect the placing at all.

Comment: No, of you call it like `groundPlacementController.yourGridSize = 10.0f;` it is definitely changing the one of `GroundPlacementController` the `GridChanger` doesn't even have a field called `yourGridSize`. Make sure you are referencing and checking the correct GameObject.

Comment: Would it matter if the GroundPlacementConroller script is attached multiple times to the same gameObject? I also just tested and because I have groundPlacementController attached multiple times to the same object, its only changing the grid size for the first, not all.

Comment: `GetComponent` allways finds only the first one! Unity isn't really made to have the same component multiple times on the same GameObject! Does that object have a parent Object or are all those components the only ones in the entire scene? Then there is a workaround

Comment: It has a parent object, also dont be confused when I dont respond until tommorow this is for a school project and I have to go.

Comment: If I have different buttons that all need to change the grid size to what their text box says how would I do that, if I accessed the text component and changed the gridSize from there I dont think it would work because their are 3 instances of text (not on the same parent)

Comment: I just realized it only finds `Text` inside of the `GroundPlacementController` script, but the buttons are actually inside a HUDCanvas

Comment: Ok then you have to get that reference on another way. e.g. adding them to a dictionary or two lists with the same index etc

Comment: Im really confused would the `list` have all the `text` values listed and would it be in a new script with the `parent` being the `text`, and then in `GridChanger` it would access those and change the grid size accordingly?

Comment: I put the text value inside the `groundPlacementController` parent but its still giving me the errors when it calls for a `TryParse`. the errors are that it `cannot convert textValue to float`, and how `textValue` is already defined

Comment: Are you there ?